# How to update Jakarta Mail version in Apache Ant?

Tags: ant, jakarta-mail

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant-javamail/1.10.12 the version of Jakarta Mail being used is 1.6.4, which is not the latest 1.6.x release. How do I properly upgrade it to 1.6.7?

Answer (score 0):

Ant doesn't ship with the Jakarta Mail jar, it has to be [added](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks) to the Ant classpath, by copying the jar into the Ant lib directory for example. Note that Ant supports the 1.6.x versions (still using the old javax.mail package) as well as the 2.x versions (using the new jakarta.mail package), so you can use the most recent version of Jakarta Mail.